# geom_contour mark specific contour (isobar) value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting to plot sea level pressure (isobars) contour on an spatial area with 2mb spacing and want a specific isobar (1015) plotted as thicker line than the others and wonder if it is possible with other function and/or with ggplot/geom_conour related function.
Below the command I sued to plot the isobar. Now any idea on how to add a oommand for the 1015 isobar?

```
syn_plot <- ggplot() +
geom_tile(data = synclas_gather_df, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=value)) +
geom_sf(data = map_bg, fill="transparent")+
geom_contour2(data = synclas_gather_df, aes(x=x,y=y,z=value), binwidth = 2, color = "black") +
scale_fill_gradientn(colours = colorRamps::matlab.like2(100), name = "hPa",breaks=0:5) +
scale_colour_gradient(guide = 'none') + facet_wrap(~key, ncol = 4) +
scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-34,29), expand = c(0, 0))+
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-9,34), expand = c(0,0))+
 theme_bw() + theme(axis.title = element_blank(),
 axis.text = element_blank(),
 axis.ticks = element_blank())

  syn_plot + geom_text_contour(data= synclas_gather_df,aes(x,y,z = value), stroke = 0.10,binwidth = 4,size=3)
```

data format:

```
 time                  lon   lat   slp
```

1 1978-12-30 12:00:00   0      40 1015.
2 1978-12-30 12:00:00   2.5    40 1013.
3 1978-12-30 12:00:00   5      40 1012.
4 1978-12-30 12:00:00   7.5    40 1010.
5 1978-12-30 12:00:00  10      40 1007.
6 1978-12-30 12:00:00  12.5    40 1005.
7 1978-12-30 12:00:00  15      40 1004.
8 1978-12-30 12:00:00  17.5    40 1003.
9 1978-12-30 12:00:00  20      40 1002.
10 1978-12-30 12:00:00  22.5    40 1001.

Comment: Please provide a sample data. You can do the trick manually, with a second ```geom_contour```and using the library ```ggnewscale```. You add the same contour plot but with a color palette that plot only that specific value.

Comment: showed in the initial post the data format but don't display as column, wonder how to do it or a way to attach a sample file?

Comment: seems no progress even with data format supplied?